# Why can't I get the innerHTML of an element which contains input type and input values?

Tags: javascript, html

Hi I want to get the `innerHTML` of a div that contains input elements with input values.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="test">
  <input type="text" id="in" />
</div>

<p id="pid">
  un texte.<input type="text" id="in" />
</p>

<input type="submit" id="in" onclick="afficher();" />
  <script>
    function afficher()
    {
      var t=document.getElementById("test");
      alert(t.innerHTML);
      var x = document.getElementById("pid");
      alert(x.innerHTML); 
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to get the inserted text in the inputs elements.

Comment: id should be identical.

Comment: just document a little [link](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_text_value.asp)

Comment: I rushed u need to add . not # to id

Comment: not even true the .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A piece of code can do the magic.

> **onblur='javascript:this.setAttribute("value",this.value)' value=""**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="test">
  <input type="text" id="in" onblur='javascript:this.setAttribute("value",this.value)' />
</div>

<p id="pid">
  un texte.<input type="text" id="in" onblur='javascript:this.setAttribute("value",this.value)' value=""/>
</p>

<input type="submit" id="in" onclick="afficher();" />
  <script>
    function afficher()
    {
      var t=document.getElementById("test");
      alert(t.innerHTML);
      var x = document.getElementById("pid");
      alert(x.innerHTML); 
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ican't know the html code inside the div ,i get it from database

Comment: Then how will you know about Ids, as mentioned in the other answers. I don't understand why you did downvote

Comment: i use the id of the div ,i don't care about what is inside the div .the exemple is just to make things more clear

Comment: If you want it as HTML, adding an event is the only way. Or If you just need values like (value1, value2, value3), you can go with query selector. Please be clear.

Comment: i need to get what is inside the div .it can be 2 inputs and a textarea for exemple.if i get the div by its id it should returns me the html code of 2 inputs with values updated and the textare with value updated

Comment: One suggestion will be, if you are creating element dynamically, then adding event won't cost you much.

Comment: As the values are not rendered at the time of page load, you can't get the values as it is as HTML. Only way is to trigger it stick the value

Comment: it works on internet explorer 5 i can get the updated value.but not in other version or other browsers

Comment: Hi  YuPPie,after many research, we cannot get the updated value if we don't submit.we have this only in ie5.so i think i'll go through your solution and a blur event on my elements inside(inputs,selects,.)

Comment: Welcome! I'll post if I can get any stuff.

Answer (score -1):

```js
function afficher()
{
  var t=document.getElementById('test').querySelectorAll("input");
  console.log(t[0].value);
  var t=document.getElementById('pid').querySelectorAll("input");
  console.log(t[0].value);
}
```

```html
<div id="test">
 <input type="text"/>
</div>

<p id="pid">
  un texte.<input type="text" />
</p>

<input type="submit" id="in" onclick="afficher();" />
```

Get div/p element using `getElementById` then use `querySelectorAll` to get input element. To get the value use `input.value`